# Closure forwarding without evaluating

Tags: swift, closures

I'm writing a logging function that also calls a CocoaLumberjack function (yes, I know about custom loggers and chose not to use it). My function is using a forward, but I have a question about how the 'forwarding' works. 
Here's my functions:

```
public func MyLogDebug(_ message: @autoclosure () -> String) {
    // some code
    MyLogMessage(message(), .debug)
}
public func MyLogMessage(_ message: @autoclosure () -> String, flag: DDLogFlag) {
    // some code
    if(myLogLevel.rawValue & flag.rawValue != 0) {
        DDLogDebug(message())
    }
}
```

My question is about the `MyLogMessage(message(), .debug)` function call. I know that avoiding string concatenation is really helpful for performance with logs, and I can see that inside `MyLogMessage` the string closure is only ran if the log level is passed. However, it look like in `MyLogDebug` the closure is also being evaluated.

I don't want to run the closure in `MyLogDebug`, so I tried to change it to `MyLogMessage(message, .debug)`, but xcode gives me an error: `Add () to forward @autoclosure parameter`.

Will my code above evaluate the closure inside `MyLogDebug`? If so, is there another way to forward the closure parameter without evaluating it?

Comment: because you are _evaluating_ the closure both cases (by invoking it) and you pass its return value to the logger only (`String`) – try to pass the reference of the closure only as a parameter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Will my code above evaluate the closure in `MyLogDebug`?

No.  The call `message()` will be wrapped in a closure by the `@autoclosure` in `MyLogMessage` and only evaluated when `message()` is subsequently called in `MyLogMessage`.

---

Here is a little standalone example to play with:

```
func DDLogDebug(_ message: String) {
    print("in DDLogDebug")
    print(message)
    print("leaving DDLogDebug")
}

public func MyLogDebug(_ message: @autoclosure () -> String) {
    // some code
    print("in MyLogDebug")
    MyLogMessage(message(), flag: true)
    print("leaving MyLogDebug")
}
public func MyLogMessage(_ message: @autoclosure () -> String, flag: Bool) {
    // some code
    print("in MyLogMessage")
    if (flag) {
        DDLogDebug(message())
    }
    print("leaving MyLogMessage")
}

MyLogDebug({ print("evaluated"); return "error message" }())
```

**Output:**

> ```
> in MyLogDebug
> in MyLogMessage
> evaluated
> in DDLogDebug
> error message
> leaving DDLogDebug
> leaving MyLogMessage
> leaving MyLogDebug
> ```

Note that the initial closure passed to `MyLogDebug` isn't evaluated until the `DDLogDebug(message())` in `MyLogMessage()`.

If you change the `flag` to `false` in the call to `MyLogMessage()`, the initial closure will never be evaluated.